# How to order physical backup of S3 data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

I'd like to order backup of data to be copied out from S3 to a physical drive (SATA HD) and to be shipped to the address. I know it's possible using [Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/), however I cannot find such option anywhere. What would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: I guess today's outage had many people reviewing their practices surrounding S3, eh?

Comment: Related: [Can I download an EBS volume within AWS to disk?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-download-an-EBS-volume-within-AWS-to-disk) at Quora

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AWS Import/Export is a service that accelerates transferring data into and out of AWS using physical storage appliances, bypassing the Internet. AWS Import/Export Disk was originally the only service offered by AWS for data transfer by mail. Disk supports transfers data directly onto and off of storage devices you own using the Amazon high-speed internal network.

Import/Export was released on May 2009, and described in this blog post - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/send-us-that-data/

Released on October of 2016 there is also [Amazon Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/), a service for customers who want to transport terabytes or petabytes of data to and from AWS, or who want to access the storage and compute power of the AWS cloud locally and cost effectively in places where connecting to the internet may not be an option.

Blog post describing the snowball service -
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-importexport-snowball-transfer-1-petabyte-per-week-using-amazon-owned-storage-appliances/

The documentation explains how to prepare a device for export, and how to create the Amazon S3 Export process.

Here are some older docs:

- [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/PackingS3Jobs.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20171122010340/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/PackingS3Jobs.html)
- [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/createanexportjob.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20171224115924/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/createanexportjob.html)

Answer (score 6):

I think you want [Amazon Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/), it's a HD shipping service by Amazon to/from AWS.

> Snowball is a petabyte-scale data transport solution that uses secure appliances to transfer large amounts of data into and **out** of the AWS cloud.
>
> With Snowball, you don’t need to write any code or purchase any hardware to transfer your data. Simply create a job in the AWS Management Console and a Snowball appliance will be automatically shipped to you